# Drag file from NSTableView to other osx application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, drag-and-drop

I want to drag a file from a NSTableView row to copy it to another application (i.e. Finder). I implemented the first two steps ('Configuring Your Table View', 'Beginning a Drag Operation') of this guide and thought that would do the trick: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Tasks/UsingDragAndDrop.html

However, when I attempt to drag a row, the row text follows my mouse but the file does not copy when released. Here's what I'm sending to my UITableView upon initialization:

```
#define librarySongDataType @"NSFileContentsPboardType"
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSUIntegerMax forLocal:YES]; // allow interapplication drags
    [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:librarySongDataType] ]; // NSFileContentsPboardType
}
```

Here's how I'm handling the drag in my NSTableView's data source (an NSArrayController):

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard
{
    NSLog(@"writeRowsWithIndexes");
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:rowIndexes];
    [pboard setData:data forType:librarySongDataType];
    return YES;
}
```

To be clear, I'm not trying to drag files into my table view, I'm just trying to drag file(s) out of it.

Comment: I think you mean `NSTableView`.  `UITableView` is only on the iPhone.

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes. I meant NSTableView. Thanks for the correction. Edited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, which document did you refer to when you wrote this line ?

```
 [self setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSUIntegerMax forLocal:YES];
```

This doesn't make sense. Don't use `NSUIntegerMax`. Use operation masks as defined [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingInfo_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDragOperation). It's written there that `NSUIntegerMax` stands for everything, but you shouldn't use it; Apple may re-define the bit in the future. You should use `NSDragOperationCopy` or something specific. If you copied that line from a webpage or a book, you should stop trusting that book/webpage.

Secondly, `forLocal:` should be `NO` to pass the data to another application; `local` here means application local.

Third, instead of just setting the archived data in

```
 [pboard setData:data forType:librarySongDataType];
```

Consider making an `NSFileWrapper` and set it using `writeFileWrapper:`, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000328-writeFileWrapper_). That way you can specify the file name to be created in Finder. Otherwise, the system doesn't have any idea what the data represent.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Your correction for the "forLocal" param fixed it for me.

Comment: Solved the problem of why only my app was recognising the pasteboard, ta.